# Extracting value and finding the minimum without merging

Tags: r, list

I'm trying to extract a subtext and get the minimum value from a list of a list in R. My initial tsv looks like this (this is a smaller version):

```
cases                                              counts
"S35718:10.63,S35585:6.75,S35708:7.28,S36617:12.23" "6.75,7.28,10.63,12.23,6.17,4.09,3.95,5.00"
"S35718:10.63"                                      "10.63"
```

And I am trying to extract the numbers after the colon and find the minimum, then I wanted to see how many in the counts column are greater than the minimum.

For instance my ideal output would be:

```
min: 6.75
greater than 6.75 in counts column: 4
```

Within this .tsv, there are approximately 100,000 lines. I've tried using gsub, but it ends up merging all the numbers such as the example below:

```
test <- gsub(".*:", "",outlier$cases)
[1]"10.63" "6.75" "7.28" "12.23" "10.63" ... all the other subsequent values
```

I would appreciate any help on this. I'm a bit of a beginner with R but would love to improve further. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

An option is to extract the numbers after the `:`, convert it to `numeric`, get the `min` and find the counts by creating a logical expression and take the `sum`

```
library(stringr)
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(tidyr)
outlier %>% 
    transmute(caselist =  str_extract_all(cases, "(?<=:)\\d+\\.\\d+"), 
              countlist = str_extract_all(counts, "[0-9.]+")) %>%
    transmute(out = map2(caselist, countlist,
         ~tibble(min = min(as.numeric(.x)), 
                 greater_than_min = sum(as.numeric(.y) >= min)))) %>%
     unnest_wider(c(out))
# A tibble: 2 x 2
#   min greater_than_min
#  <dbl>            <int>
#1  6.75                4
#2 10.6                 1
```

#### data

```
outlier <- structure(list(cases = c("S35718:10.63,S35585:6.75,S35708:7.28,S36617:12.23", 
"S35718:10.63"), counts = c("6.75,7.28,10.63,12.23,6.17,4.09,3.95,5.00", 
"10.63")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -2L))
```